# Why doesn't scipy.signal.filtfilt implement zero-padding?

Tags: python, scipy, filtering

In my field, zero-padding is typically used to deal with edge effects when applying a bandpass filter. However, in `scipy`, `filtfilt` supports three padding options: "odd", "even", and "constant". I was wondering if anyone knew whether zero-padding was ever considered, and, if so, why it wasn't implemented.

Alternatively, are there any papers comparing zero-padding to any of the options that *are* implemented in `scipy`? I haven't been able to find anything in my field (fMRI), but there might be other fields that I'm not familiar with that have covered this.

Comment: You'll have to ask the `scipy` developers if you want definitive explanations of their design decisions. As for asking for papers, that's off topic for SO.

Comment: Maybe it's easy to apply 0 padding yourself before hand.  Or there's some other filter in the package that does what you want.